# SQL update records in one table that satisify a query result on a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update a number of records in one table that are based on the result of a query from a related table. In this example, I have 150 records in tbl_events that I want to update with "entered_by", and in order to get those 150 records, I need to match the selection with the 150 records in tbl_locations has the value "needs update" in the notes field. The "Entered_by" value DOES NOT exist in tbl_locations, I'm just trying to update the table based on relationship pre-conditions. But I get the following error:

```
UPDATE TBL_EVENTS 
SET Entered_By = 'Fred' 
FROM GRSTBL_EVENTS as sp
JOIN TBL_LOCATIONS as so
On sp.Location_ID = so.Location_ID
  AND so.Notes =(SELECT Notes from TBL_LOCATIONS where Notes = 'needs update')
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data structures correctly then you need to update the entered_by field if there are any notes in the related tbl_locations table.

If so then the following, which is known as a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) should do what you want

```
UPDATE TBL_EVENTS 
SET Entered_By = 'Fred' 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM   TBL_LOCATIONS 
  WHERE  TBL_LOCATIONS.Location_ID = TBL_EVENTS.Location_ID
  AND    TBL_LOCATIONS.Notes = 'needs update'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use in

```
UPDATE TBL_EVENTS
SET Entered_By = 'Fred'
FROM GRSTBL_EVENTS as sp
JOIN TBL_LOCATIONS as so
On sp.Location_ID = so.Location_ID
AND so.Notes  in (SELECT Notes from TBL_LOCATIONS where Notes = 'needs update')
```

Comment: How is this IN clause different to `so.Notes = 'needs update'?